# Is there a phrase "a carry-and-top"?

Tags: meaning, hyphenation

I've encountered a phrase that I can't find out in spite of my attempts to look up in several dictionaries and browsing online. I've tried Ludwig too, but still can't find satisfying answer.

It's related to a limit, similar to a floor and ceiling limit.

My question is, is the term 'a carry-and-top' is usable in written English? And if the answer is yes, does it fit the context I've provided above?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In what context did you encounter the phrase? Mathematics, engineering, finance...?

Comment: You're sure it wasn't "carry on top" / "carry-on top"?

Comment: Similar to @EdwinAshworth's question, is it possible you were hearing a description of the notation being used (e.g. "caret on top")?

Comment: I don’t understand “floor limit” or “ceiling limit”. Airlines limit the dimensions of carry-on luggage.

Comment: @Xanne It sounds like they're using the mathematical sense of "limit".